# Error deploying war in JBoss4.2 "Packages waiting for a deployer"

Tags: deployment, war, jboss-4.2.x

I get this error straight away after a really long streak of Java exceptions.

I have check the Java JDK version on `Maven` to install, and for running on server (bin/run.bat), I have no problem running another `war` files generated in other computers.

The files generated consist of:

1. `nameofproject-version`
2. `nameofproject-version.war`

What is may causing this problem?

```java
--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@1338ffed { url=file:***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0/ }
deployer: null
status: null
state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
watch: file:***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0/
altDD: null
lastDeployed: 1475089977984
lastModified: 1475089738113
mbeans:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@2947d452 { url=***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0.war }
deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:***jobss/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7284564640094328851***-war-1.0-exp.war/ deployment failed
state: FAILED
watch: file:***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0.war
altDD: null
lastDeployed: 1475089965442
lastModified: 1475089965348
mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@1338ffed { url=file:***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0/ }
deployer: null
status: null
state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
watch: file:***jboss/server/default/deploy/***-war-1.0/
altDD: null
lastDeployed: 1475089977984
lastModified: 1475089738113
mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=***-war-1.0.war,id=692573266
State: FAILED
Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:***jboss/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7284564640094328851***-war-1.0-exp.war/ deployment failed

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=***-war-1.0.war,id=692573266
State: FAILED
Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:***jboss/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7284564640094328851***-war-1.0-exp.war/ deployment failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are so many possible causes, and almost all of them are at coderanch.com , and not even with answer. I'll write what worked to me.

*The deployer was not detecting the Hibernate DBB connection, So the relevant exception trace was including packages from `Hibernate`.

It may be caused also by a different JDK version used at compiling time.

Or even due to missing the file with `.war` extension.